# Git rebase with conflicting branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I currently have the following situation in my git repository

```
A - B - C - D - E - F (master)
     \- D' - E' - G (branch)
```

I branched out from D at some point, but it seems that someone went back and introduced a `C` commit and then I was completely out of sync. Now, I want to rebase my changes in `G(branch)` to `F(master)`. That is, I would like to have the following instead

```
A - B - C - D - E - F(master)
                     \- G(branch)
```

In other words, completely discarding `D'`, and `E'`. What is the way to do this? 
I tried `git rebase` but I was getting many conflicts that kept asking me to merge changes in `D`' and `E`'.

Comment: You need to **reparent** the commit `G`. Reparenting is a rebase without changing the ordering of the commits that are being reparented.

Comment: @0andriy That describes any rebase; you're basically introducing "reparent" (a nice word, by the way, from the XWindow system and Unix processes) as a synonym for "rebase".

Comment: I would cherry pick g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rebase onto `master`, carrying only one commit (that being `G`):

```
git rebase --onto master HEAD~1
```

The `HEAD~1` specifies the "upstream", overriding whatever default upstream is used. `git rebase` will replay only commits in the current branch that are not in upstream. So that isolates just the one commit. `--onto` specifies where to hard reset to before cherry picking the commits.

Speaking of cherry-picking, we could also just do the equivalent steps manually:

```
# drop all work, and just become equivalent to master
git reset --hard master

# pick just G out of the dropped work, bringing it into master
git cherry-pick <sha-of-G>
```

A third way would be to do an **interactive** rebase:

```
git rebase -i
```

then edit out the unwanted commits, keeping only G. If you don't know interactive rebase, this approach introduces a useful skill, so is arguably the best of the three.